# Block calls and sms in Iphone iOS while application running

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

while using app I want to block all incoming calls and sms. How can I do this? I know example link http://tech.ruimaninfo.com/?p=83. But there are errors in code.It should work at least on jailbroken iphone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is some code that I've adapted from that website, and works for me on my non jailbroken device:

Firstly add "CoreTelephony.framework" to your project then import it into your view controller like so:

```
#import <CoreTelephony/CoreTelephonyDefines.h>
```

Next, add the following code:

```
extern NSString const *kCTSMSMessageReceivedNotification;
extern NSString const *kCTSMSMessageReplaceReceivedNotification;
extern NSString const *kCTSIMSupportSIMStatusNotInserted;
extern NSString const *kCTSIMSupportSIMStatusReady;

typedef struct __CTCall CTCall;
extern NSString *CTCallCopyAddress(void*, CTCall *);

void * CTSMSMessageSend(id server,id msg);
typedef struct __CTSMSMessage CTSMSMessage;
NSString *CTSMSMessageCopyAddress(void *, CTSMSMessage *);
NSString *CTSMSMessageCopyText(void *, CTSMSMessage *);

int CTSMSMessageGetRecordIdentifier(void * msg);
NSString * CTSIMSupportGetSIMStatus();
NSString * CTSIMSupportCopyMobileSubscriberIdentity();

id CTSMSMessageCreate(void* unknow/*always 0*/,NSString* number,NSString* text);
void * CTSMSMessageCreateReply(void* unknow/*always 0*/,void * forwardTo,NSString *text);

id CTTelephonyCenterGetDefault(void);
void CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver(id, id, CFNotificationCallback, NSString *, void *,int);
void CTTelephonyCenterRemoveObserver(id,id,NSString*,void*);
int CTSMSMessageGetUnreadCount(void);

void * CTCallDisconnect(CTCall *call);

static void callback(CFNotificationCenterRef center, void *observer, CFStringRef name, const void *object, CFDictionaryRef userInfo) {

    NSString *notifyname = (__bridge NSString *)name;

    if ([notifyname isEqualToString:@"kCTCallIdentificationChangeNotification"]) {

        NSDictionary *info = (__bridge NSDictionary *)userInfo;

        CTCall *call = (__bridge CTCall *)[info objectForKey:@"kCTCall"];

        NSString *caller = CTCallCopyAddress(NULL, call);

        NSLog(@"RECEIVED CALL: %@", caller);

        CTCallDisconnect(call);

    }

}

static void signalHandler(int sigraised) {

    printf("\nInterrupted.\n");
    exit(0);

}
```

And in viewDidLoad or some other appropriate method, add the following:

```
id ct = CTTelephonyCenterGetDefault();
CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver(ct, NULL, callback, NULL, NULL, CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorHold);

sig_t oldHandler = signal(SIGINT, signalHandler);
if (oldHandler == SIG_ERR) {

    printf("Could not establish new signal handler");
    exit(1);

}

printf("Starting run loop and watching for notification.\n");
CFRunLoopRun();
```

For now this code is merely a proof of concept and would have to be expanded upon for error handling and whatnot, but you should get the idea.

Comment: thanks for answer. so Block calls and sms starts after function in viewDidLoad?

Comment: That's where you begin to receive callbacks and eventually block those, yes.

Comment: thi code gives error , redefine CTCall and incompatible conversation of nullable pointer to CTCall