# Blocking incoming and outgoing calls from iOS Enterprise App using Private API

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, core-telephony

I looked at lot of different posts in SO and others blogs,it looks blocking calls in iOS is possible. I followed the below url and tried in my project, but it is not blocking the calls. I tested in my iOS8 device.

[Block calls and sms in Iphone iOS while application running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692551/block-calls-and-sms-in-iphone-ios-while-application-running)

Comment: I would be careful…. I am guessing something like an app preventing a call not only would be dangerous but not even approved. Digging further into that link you provided I saw this note: `Carriers can use this information to write applications that provide services only for their own subscribers`. Unless you are a subscriber, I wouldn't do it.

Comment: Aaaaah. Never mind. I just saw your title change….

Comment: @logixologist: My App is an Enterprise app, apple approving is not a blocker for us. is there any private API which can does this?

Comment: I am not aware of any.

Comment: It's not possible since iOS 7 because all necessary APIs are protected by entitlements that can be used only on jailbroken devices.

Answer (score 0):

For only testing purpose you should use quite old Apple devices that are not well protected. I will definitely recommend to use old iPhone 4 with Jailbreak in it. I was using iOS 6 to test hide API and code examples that are presented in [this](http://tech.ruimaninfo.com/?p=83) article is working fine.

Nevertheless CoreTelephony APIs are **not working on iOS 7 and iOS 8** as well so you should investigate more to find out with API you should use.